# VS C# application - faster in Studio than on Different Comp

Tags: c#, ms-access, aceoledb

Odd question - I know - be gentle - first post.

Did a bunch of searching, and maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms.

I've got a VS C# app that I run from the development environment (poor form - I get it, but, I do.)  When a different user (on a different machine) runs the Release version (No VS at all, so I compiled it, and sent it to them), they run at a MUCH slower speed when accessing Microsoft Access databases.  (ACE.OLEDB.16.0).  Like orders of magnitude slower.  (Something on my dev machine, inside VS runs in 4 minutes, and then runs in 2.5 hours on theirs.

Access drivers are the same on both machines.

Not sure where to even go to try and figure this out.  Thoughts?  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thx.

Comment: Make sure they have the 64 bit version of office installed. Also the [tag:visual-studio-2022] tag is not relevant to this question. Please remove it.

Comment: Ok, without question the first question? Is there a network or shared folder involved, or is this 100% stand alone on that target computer? (and if yes, try un-plugging network connection on that computer - see if any  change occurs).

Comment: It's impossible to know what the issue is from the information that has been posted. Start with a repair of Access on the target computer. It's recommended to use the  [Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358) - it's also available as a NuGet package ([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access)). See the note in the pink box [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution) for the reason.

Comment: Another possibility is that the database is corrupt. Try opening the database with Access. You may also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70209998/10024425). I believe that ACE attempts to report any issues to MS. Is this computer connected to the internet? You may consider using JET instead which is only available for 32-bit. If using JET, compile your app as 32-bit. The following may be helpful: [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).

Comment: I recommend posting a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see if there are any issues with your code.

Comment: Hey, all.  Thanks for the comments.  New information.  This only runs well within the IDE.  I compiled and ran it from my (dev) machine (Release version), so outside the IDE, and it runs for 2.5 hours.  I then ran it again, inside the IDE (again, same machine) and it ran in 4 minutes.  Compacted and repaired as well - so it doesn't appear to be a corrupted database.  This is all running locally on the machine - no network sharing involved.  Trying to think how I stick some reproducible code up here - but it's a pretty involved set of code as a part of a bigger application.

Comment: Continued:  Compiler is set for x64.

Comment: For better visibility, you should [edit] you question to add additional information instead of putting it into comments.

Comment: When you write "within the IDE", do you also run the Release configuration or is it the Debug configuration?